# Turn Emails into Usernames With MySQL Query

Tags: mysql

I am adding a username field to my database, and I want to populate it with the username portion of the email addresses the users have supplied...

I dont have many users, so I dont expect any conflicts.

What would a query look like to take the username portion of an email address and save it to the username column?

Thank you

Comment: *to take the username portion of an email address* `SUBSTRING_INDEX(email, '@', 1)` *save it to the username column* `UPDATE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably suggest doing it in the code that will be creating the insert statement but it can be done in the insert statement itself too.

```
INSERT INTO yourtable SET username = LOWER(SUBSTR(useremail,1,LOCATE('@',useremail) - 1))
```

I included the LOWER so the style of the user name would be consistent in case a person entered their email address in MixedCase.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot Dave, but shouldnt that be update yourtable set username....

Comment: In the absence of an actual query in your our original question which said _I am adding a username_ I made the assumption you were inserting a row. If you are in fact updating existing rows then an update would be correct and `useremail` would be the name of the column that contains that value.